# TTURLMap - Where do you populate it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20, ttnavigator

I've been playing around with the `Three20` framework and I'm looking to utilize the launcher aspect of it for starters. I've been reading about `TTNavigator` and `TTURLMap`. So if I'm correct, the following pieces of code achieve the same functionality.

```
LoginViewController *login = [LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginView" bundle:nil];
[[appdelegate navigationControler] pushViewController:login];
[login release];
```

and

```
TTNavigator *navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
TTURLMap *map = [navigator URLMap];
[map from:@"tt://LoginViewController/initWithNibName:/bundle:" toViewController:[LoginViewController class]];
```

and invoking

```
[[TTNavigator navigator] openURLAction:
  [[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"tt://LoginViewController/LoginView/"] applyAnimated:YES]]
```

So, my question now is, when do you populate the `TTURLMap` with the URLs and the View Controllers? Do you populate all your view controllers in some method like `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method and just use the `openURLAction:` in all your view controllers? Or do you populate the map on an as needed basis, which really doesn't save anything in terms of effort / boiler plate code?

Thanks, 
Teja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you populate all your view controllers in some method like applicationDidFinishLaunching: method and just use the openURLAction: in all your view controllers?

Yes.

You also use [`TTTableLinkedItem`](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_table_linked_item.php)'s to open links.